# How to avoid [Vue warn]: Injection "xxxx" not found

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3

I'm using inject/provide pattern in nuxt composition-api.
For example, Component A inject the function provided by Component B which is parent of Component A like below.

```js
//Component B 
const test = () => {}
provide('test', test)
```

```js
//Component A 
const test = inject<Function>('test')
```

However when I want to use Component A without Component B, this warn is shown on console. I understand it's saying but in this case it doesn't need to use ''test'' function. Are there any way to avoid this warning ?

> [Vue warn]: Injection "test" not found

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To avoid the warning, specify a default value (the 2nd argument to `inject()`):

```js
const test = inject<Function>('test', () => {})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-default-injection?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FComponentA.vue)